# Install Magisk in TWRP, with "Keep DM-Verity/AVB 2.0" option?

Tags: twrp, magisk, dm-verity

I want to flash the Magisk ZIP while keeping dm-verity and AVB 2.0.

The Magisk ZIP detects my encrypted `/data` partition and keeps force encryption, but always disables dm-verity and AVB 2.0 when flashed with TWRP. This leads to the inconvenience that I have to restore the "stock boot image" (with TWRP) and flash it again in Magisk Manager.

It's better if dm-verity and AVB is preserved at the first flash in TWRP.

Comment: @beeshyams I know I can restore the stock image and flash again, but the question is I want to avoid it, by keeping verity on first flash.

Comment: Did you try version 17.1 latest one? Claims to keep dm verity

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the response. I've flashed Magisk 17.1 and it's working. See my own answer which provides an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Magisk 17.1 (introduced by topjohnwu in [this commit](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/commit/70d3b2433819ad3d744245c6d83b760bab82a2b2)), Magisk installer ZIP now detects `system_root_image` and keeps dm-verity/AVB 2.0 when being flashed in recovery. This should solve the issue most of the times (at least with my OnePlus 5 and OnePlus 6).

Alternatively, create a file at `/data/.magisk` with the following content:

```
KEEPFORCEENCRYPT=true
KEEPVERITY=true
```

This file will be parsed by the installer script ([here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/70d3b2433819ad3d744245c6d83b760bab82a2b2/scripts/util_functions.sh#L150)) and the settings will be respected.